# How to intercept all http(s) requests on ios WKWebView?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm having an Android app that relies heavily on `shouldIntercept` on the `WebView` ported to iOS ideally using `WKWebView`. Is there a way to implement something similar to `shouldIntercept` for all http and https calls?

Edit: the android webview will let me intercept all resources, images, videos, html, Javascript, etc. Is there some way to do that on ios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this github repository](https://github.com/WildDylan/WKWebViewWithURLProtocol) called as WKWebViewWithURLProtocol Casolorz. This library enables you to use NSURLProtocol to intercept your network requests using method swizzling.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is that accepted by the App Store or will it get rejected?

Comment: I am using it and Apple hasn't rejected it. Give it a try :)

Comment: @casolorz How exactly did this work for you? I only see basic requests. Would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: It is my understanding that we didn't end up using this because of some other issues. Sorry I'm not the iOS dev, I'm the Android dev, I was just trying to help find a solution.

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla, If you are targetting iOS 10.0 and lower, inorder to intercept all the requests, you need to use this https://github.com/WildDylan/WKWebViewWithURLProtocol  and custom NSURLProtocol https://www.raywenderlich.com/2292-using-nsurlprotocol-with-swift. 
If you are targetting above iOS 11.0, you can directly use WKURLSchemeHandler.

Comment: @RizwanAhmed, @casolorz - thanks for the response. But just to clarify, `WKURLSchemeHandler` doesn't let you handle http or https and with `WKWebViewWithURLProtocol` I only see basic requests (no images or fonts or xhr) same as when using `WKNavigationDelegate`, I could be using it wrong. But anyways, we decided to go with a web service for what we were trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla, in that case, use the library which I have mentioned. It does everything perfectly. :)